# Hystrix command does not run in Hystrix environment

Tags: aop, aspectj, hystrix

I am having an issue with my Hystrix commands. If the call to hystrix wrapped method comes from within the class, the hystrix-wrapped method does not run in Hystrix enviroment

In that case I see logs as

```
05-02-2018 22:51:25.809 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-3] INFO  c.i.q.v.e.ConnectorImpl.populateFIDSchema -
    populating FID Schema
```

But, if I make call to the same method from outside the class, I see it running it in Hystrix enviroment

```
 05-02-2018 22:54:53.735 [hystrix-ConnectorImpl-1] INFO  c.i.q.v.e.ConnectorImpl.populateFIDSchema -
    populating FID Schema
```

I am wrapping my method with HystrixCommand like this

```
 @HystrixCommand(commandKey = "getSchemaCommand", fallbackMethod = "getSchemaCommandFallback")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to @pvpkiran's answer, this is not a limitation of AspectJ, but a limitation Spring AOP. Spring AOP is a solution that tries to implement a *subset* of AspectJ through proxies, and the proxy based approach is what causing the *advices not being called when the calls are not made through the proxy*.

See [Spring AOP capabilities and goals](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn) and [AOP Proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-proxies) in the Spring Framework Reference for more details.

AspectJ on the other hand directly modifies the bytecode of the advised class, involves no proxies at all, and doesn't suffer from the limitation of the proxy based Spring AOP.

AspectJ is superior in pretty much all aspects to Spring AOP so I would advise you to switch over from Spring AOP to AspectJ (you don't need to ditch Spring for this as Spring and AspectJ can work together very well).

Comment: Your statements about self-invocation limitations of Spring AOP as opposed to AspectJ are correct, I could not have said it any better. But do you also happen to know why Spring AOP should play any role here at all? As I mentioned in my comment under the other answer, Hystrix does not use AOP out of the box.

Comment: @kriegaex I'm not really familiar with Hystrix to be honest, I just saw the question and the other answer and said, hey, this is the same pattern like in every tenth question about AspectJ, because people are confused whether they are actually using AspectJ or Spring AOP, or what do these two technologies even have to do with each other in the first place. And we can't figure out too much from the OP anyway, because it doesn't have any details about specific configuration of Hystrix in his Spring context. But his problem is most likely the above ^^ :)

Comment: I never used Hystrix either. Yes, maybe @Pretty uses some kind of Spring plugin. We can only speculate until he/she adds more details to his/her question.

Comment: @kriegaex You are definitely right, and I'm willing to change/delete my answer if it turns out I'm wrong with my assumptions.

Comment: I think you won't need to do that because it will turn out to be the right answer. As I said, probably the OP does use some sort of Spring plugin, she already confirmed that she is using Spring. My assumption is that [Hystrix-Javanica](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica) (AOP-based unlike Hystrix core) from the "contribution" part of Hystrix is used, either directly or indirectly via [Spring Cloud Netflix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix). The former link describes how to configure Javanica with either Spring AOP or AspectJ.

Comment: Hello everyone, I am sorry for late response. I am using Spring AOP.

Comment: @Pretty pvpkiran changed his answer to be the total opposite of his original answer since I pointed out in my answer that he's wrong (just look at his last edit). It's up to you to decide which answer deserves to be the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of Spring AOP (Hystrix-Javanica is based on AOP).
When you call a method locally, it doesn't go through a proxy and hence it doesn't really run in Hystrix environment, instead it runs as if it's another method.

But when you make a call from outside the class, it goes through proxy and hence it works.

This is true of many other functionalities. Another example is `@Cacheable`

When you call from outside the class, Hystrix (Spring AOP) intercepts the call and wraps it around its own environment. But when you do a call locally, it cannot intercept the call.

Comment: Is this because I am using Spring?

Comment: No. Its because Hystrix uses AspectJ for Intercepting calls. Not because of spring

Comment: @pvpkiran the rejected edit is being discussed here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362985/author-rejected-edit-actively-harms-readability

Comment: I think this answer is wrong for two reasons: (1) According to the [Hystrix FAQ](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/FAQ%20:%20General#why-not-use-aop) the product does **not** use AOP. (2) Even if it or one of its plug-in modules did use AOP, AspectJ would just **not** have the limitation about self-invocation mentioned in the answer because it does not use proxies. The statement is only true for Spring AOP, but never for AspectJ.

Comment: @kriegaex . May be I am not clear in my answer. Will update it. If you look at the question here you can see `@HystrixCommand` which is not part of Hystrix-core. They are coming from another module called hystrix-javanica (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica). This uses AOP.

Comment: You are a little late, I already mentioned Hystrix-Javanica in my comment below Nándor's answer. I also linked to the description about how to configure it with AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. Your statement that AspectJ is the cause of the self-invocation problem was and still is false even after your update. Once again: AspectJ is **not** the problem, Spring AOP is. Just use AspectJ instead and be happy, it will work. I know this without having tried because I know how AspectJ works. With all due respect: Nándor is right, you are wrong.