# Spring cloud Hystrix not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, netflix

I am calling two private methods marked with @HystrixCommand from inside the public method. But the Hystrix circuit breaker is not working.
If I move the @HystrixCommand to public parent method it works but I don't want it on the top.

```
public PersonResponseModel getPerson(String nino,int id)
    {
        //person data from database
        Person person=fetchPerson(nino);
        PersonResponseModel personResponseModel=personMapper.personToPersonResponse(person);

        //Get org data from extenal resource
        OrganizationDTO organizationDTO=getOrganizationData(id);
}

   @HystrixCommand
    private OrganizationDTO getOrganizationData(int OrganizationId)
    {
        randomlyRunLong();  // Testing 
        ResponseEntity<OrganizationDTO> reponse= organizationClient.getOrganization(OrganizationId);
        OrganizationDTO organizationDTO=reponse.getBody();
        return organizationDTO;
    }

    @HystrixCommand
    private Person fetchPerson(String nino)
    {
        return personRepository.findByNino(nino);
    }
```

It is a very common scenario I hope spring cloud and Hystrix should support this.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628164/hystrix-command-does-not-run-in-hystrix-environment/48628297#48628297

Comment: I have checked your answer. Do you mean if I move these private methods to separate class it will work?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. You are right ..

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved by moving the individual method annotated with the @HystrixCommmand to separate class file and circuit breaker started working.

Thanks, pvpkiran.