# hystrix Fallback is not getting called for invidiual Item in Collection

Tags: grails, groovy, hystrix

I had to call falback for each item in the list in case of any error and continue processing other items, is it possible?

```
@Subscriber('dupe-user-check')
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "subscriptionSearchFallback")
void duplicateUserCheck(Object payload) {
// call to other microservice
//Validate response and see if user already exist for this item
//If yes
throw new DuplicateUserException("User Already Exist. Response Payload 
                            ${response.json.toString()}")
.........................................................
}



void subscriptionSearchFallback(Object payload, Throwable throwable) {
        logger.error("SUBSCRIPTION SEARCH FALLBACK :", throwable)
        itemStatusUpdateService.updateItemStatus(item.itemKey,DUPE_EMAIL_FAILED)
}
```

Currently it's not going to fallback.

Exception Trace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   ValidationDuplicateEmailService::User Already Exist. Response Payload
>   {"statusDesc":["999 - User information is not
>   valid"],"hasErrors":true,"statusCode":"999"}  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
>     at
>   com.xyz.ValidationDuplicateEmailService.duplicateUserCheck(ValidationDuplicateEmailService.groovy:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
>     at
>   grails.events.subscriber.MethodSubscriber.call(MethodSubscriber.groovy:51)
>     at
>   org.grails.events.EventSubscriberTrigger.proceed(EventSubscriberTrigger.groovy:31)
>     at
>   org.grails.events.bus.ExecutorEventBus$_buildNotificationCallable_closure1$_closure3.doCall(ExecutorEventBus.groovy:36)
>     at
>   org.grails.events.bus.ExecutorEventBus$_buildNotificationCallable_closure1$_closure3.call(ExecutorEventBus.groovy)
>     at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because the method with the @HystrixCommand is called from within the same class.

As discussed in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628164/hystrix-command-does-not-run-in-hystrix-environment/48628297) question, this is a limitation of Spring's AOP.

Comment: Thanks for the response Davin... so this should work?

 @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "subscriptionSearchFallback")
    @Subscriber('dupe-user-check')
    void duplicateUserCheck(Object payload) {
    ..............................................
}
Here Subscriber is from 'grails.events.annotation.*'

Comment: Nope still didn't worked, updated the exception trace.

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot application?  If so, ensure you have @EnableCircuitBreaker on a configuration class.  Here is some documentation https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Comment: Grails, yes it is enabled, it's working fine in other services, as they are getting called from outside [just as you suggested]...but here somehow it's not going to fallback. I updated above as per your suggestions.

Comment: Could it be an issue with AOP and the two annotations on the same method.  Does it work if you remove @Subscriber?

Comment: it works when i moved the code and fallback method to another class. i will accept the answer, thanks