# HystrixCommand Annotation does not work when used to wrap Spring Integration Gateway Calls

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, hystrix

I want to add a fallback to my Gateway call in  Spring Integration Application.

I have wrapped the call to the gateway in a method with the @HystrixCommand annotation and provided the name of the fallback method in fallbackMethod attribute.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getMockData")
public String gatewayCallGetMessage(String name) {
   return serviceGateway.getMessage(name);
}

public String getMockData(String name) {
  return "mock data";
}
```

I have also defined the fallback method in same class.

My Gateway interface is as below,

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface HystrixServiceGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "get.request.channel", replyChannel = "reply.channel")
    String getMessage(String name);

}
```

I have **spring-cloud-starter-hystrix** dependency in the classpath/pom.xml.
Also, I have **@EnableHystrix** annotation in my Spring Boot Application class as below.

```
@EnableHystrix
public class HystrixIntegrationApplication {

...
}
```

But, when the service is down the gateway call does not go through but the fallback method is not getting executed.

I have shared the code I used to  reproduce my issue is as below,
https://github.com/sri420/hystrix-integration-demo

If anyone has faced a similar issue and know of a way address it , please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The method gatewayCallGetMessage is being called from getByName which is in the same class.  Methods with @HystrixCommand can not be called from within the same class.

As discussed in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628164/hystrix-command-does-not-run-in-hystrix-environment/48628297) question this is a limitation of Spring's AOP.

Comment: please, include in your answer the possibility to overcome the problem with the `exposeProxy = true`. See JavaDocs in the `ProxyConfig.setExposeProxy()`

Comment: @ArtemBilan I do not know how to achieve this for the given example.  I have tried using @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) as per the JavaDocs without success. I am happy to add this to the answer if you could elaborate on your suggestion.